# add a hook in prog-mode except a particular mode

Tags: emacs, hook

i have a function

```
(defun a--before-test-save-hook()
  "Test of before save hook"
  (message "foobar"))
```

and i want to run it in `prog-mode` except `python-mode`,
but i have no clue now
and i just `add-hook` in `prog-mode` including `python-mode`

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode (lambda ()
                       (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'a-test-before-save-hook t t)))
```

i have try

```
(defun a-test-before-save-hook()
  "Test of before save hook"
  (unless (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (message "foobar")))
```

but i want a better try,any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Your solution is exactly correct.

Comment: As a general note you might want to use `(derived-mode-p 'python-mode)` instead of `(eq major-mode 'python-mode)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's better, but you could do:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless (derived-mode-p 'python-mode)
              (add-hook 'before-save-hook
                        #'a-test-before-save-hook t t))))
```

Of course, my own reflex is to ask "what makes Python special?".  The answer might let you replace the `(derived-mode-p 'python-mode)` test with something that goes more directly at the heart of the issue (e.g. maybe the issue is related to indentation-significance and would hence also apply to Coffeescript and Haskell and maybe you could check `electric-indent-inhibit` instead).

Comment: what makes python special? because,this function doesn't work as well as other major prog mode,actually,it is a function about automatic indent region before save,and python is sensitive with indent,furthermore,i have a better choice,sorry for replying you so late